# Error when using SharpDevelop

Tags: c#, visual-studio, outlook, sharpdevelop

I have some code:

```
Outlook.Application outLookApp = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.Inspector inspector = outLookApp.ActiveInspector();
Outlook.NameSpace nameSpace = outLookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
Outlook.MAPIFolder inbox = nameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
String sCriteria = "[SenderEmailAddress] = 'somebody@somewhare.com'";
Outlook.Items filteredItems = inbox.Items.Restrict(sCriteria);
// totaly sure that count > 0;
Outlook.MailItem item = filteredItems[1];
```

In the last line I have error: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)". I don't know why. Previous I used VisualStudio 2010 but my trial has expired. Is there any hope to run this on SharpDevelop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't look like a SharpDevelop error, it looks like you just need a cast. Try this:

```
Outlook.MailItem item = (Outlook.MailItem)filteredItems[1];
```

(this is assuming that the objects in `filteredItems` are actually of this type. You may want to test if this is the case before this assignment.)

Also, you could use Visual Studio 2010 Express - http://www.microsoft.com/express/

Comment: Thanks this helps me. But I am pretty sure that this code works in VS without a cast. Is there any difference between this tools?

Comment: The error you're showing comes from the compiler, not SharpDevelop or Visual Studio. Could it be you're using the Mono framework with SharpDevelop? This would use a different compiler that might give different messages. Or maybe you just have different settings for the same compiler across the two development environments.